# UICustomActionSheet not calling delegate method to handle events

Tags: ios, xcode, uiactionsheet, uiactionsheetdelegate

i am using [this](https://github.com/pchernovolenko/UICustomActionSheet) example in my code. And it is working just fine for now but when i tap on a button it did not respond or call any method. here is my code:

```
UICustomActionSheet* customActionSheet = [[UICustomActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil buttonTitles:@[@"Cancel",@"Delete picture", @"Take a new photo", @"Choose from existing"]];
    [customActionSheet setButtonColors:@[[UIColor redColor]]];
    [customActionSheet setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [customActionSheet setSubtitle:@"Select your Choice"];
    [customActionSheet setSubtitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [customActionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

and here is method that needs to be called

```
-(void)customActionSheet:(UICustomActionSheet *)customActionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"%d",buttonIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your **delegate**. You have set it `nil`. Set it to `self` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Welcome. If that helps you, you can mark it as correct answer. Happy Coding.

Comment: yup i will in 7 mins